# How to change the colour of cell background in grid view without any using any touch event of grid view

Tags: java, android, gridview

```
package com.example.dhavalpatel.atira;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class second extends ActionBarActivity { 
     GridView gv;  

    String[] value1=value1=new String[]{"0","1","0","1","0"};
    String imc_met;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        gv=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ad = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,value1);

        gv.setAdapter(ad);
   }
```

So I have set a grid view with an array adapter to add value in a cell. I want an event which checks the value of the cell and if it is 1 then it changes the background color, but without any touch on the cell. As for example `OnClick` event or `OnSelectedItem` etc. Non of that can be used.

I want to check every cell value on activity loading. I mean that when activity is called it should display the grid view with 0 or 1 as the cell value and where the cell value is 1 the background color should be red.

Comment: you have to make custom array adapter and than check the value in getview change the background according to it

Comment: Can you please write an sample code. Or may be edit my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `getView()` of your `ArrayAdapter` and set the background color of you view.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, value1) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            String value = getItem(position);
            if (value.equals("0")) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
           // Updating the text color.
           TextView textView= (TextView) view;
           textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            return view;
        }
    };
```

Comment: I am not able to set size of column and text colour, can you help.

Comment: Updated my answer have a look.

Comment: Thanks, and what about column size?

Comment: you can set it in the GridView xml layout android:columnWidth="@dimen/width"

Comment: Not working. Xml code have no effect on grid view